# jquery - animate div in different direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a site like [THIS](https://www.deepend.com.au/).
my background slider still not too well. it still adds another slide in right of the active slide and turns into over width 
and div slide in the top of that didn't change into another div, 
I'm very new in javascript

Complete code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function do_slide() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 6000);
  }
  do_slide();
  $('.child img').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
  $('.child img').mouseleave(function() {
    do_slide();
  });

  var slideCount = $('#main_slide .child img').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#main_slide .child img').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#main_slide .child img').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#main_slide').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#main_slide .child').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#main_slide .child img:last-child').prependTo('#main_slide .child');

  //                Slide Background
  function moveRight() {
    $('#main_slide .child').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 700, function() {
      $('#main_slide .child img:first-child').appendTo('#main_slide .child');
      $('#main_slide .child').css('left', '');
    });
    $('#slide_content .child').animate({
      left: "300px"
    }, 700, function() {
      $('#slide_content .child div:first-child').appendTo('#slide_content .child');
      $('#slide_content .child').css('left', '');
    });
  };

});
```

```css
#main_slide {
  position: relative;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /*border: solid thin yellow;*/
}

#main_slide .child {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  list-style: none;
  /*border: solid thin blue;*/
}

#main_slide .child img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  /*border: solid thin red;*/
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#slide_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
  /*float: right;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}

#slide_content .child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_slide">
  <div class="child">
    <img style="background-color: violet" src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
    <img style="background-color: blue" src="img/bg2.jpg" alt="">
    <img style="background-color: green" src="img/bg3.jpg" alt="">
    <img style="background-color: pink" src="img/bg4.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="slide_content">
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Title2</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Title3</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Title4</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#slide_content .child').animate({
                  left: "200px"
                });
```

try "left:200px" or any value  instead of "right". it will work.. certainly its because of the large width of the background slider. fix the slider and everything should work fine

Comment: hi shiva thank for helping, the div was slide right, but did'n change into next div